# split function is not working with the regex provided

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

this is my take on the problem. i have successfully passed 3/4. the only thing messing up my solution is that extra white space after ‘telebubbles’. how do i progress further? i’m not good with replace.

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
let k=str.split(/[\s-_]?(?=[A-Z])/g).join('-').toLowerCase()
console.log(k)
return k
}

spinalCase('This Is Spinal Tap');//passed
spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap")//passed
spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show")//passed
spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh")//not working
spinalCase("AllThe-small Things")//passed
```

Comment: Maybe try this? `/ |[\s-_]?(?=[A-Z])/g` besides, there are 5 tests, not 4 :)

Comment: Try `.split(/[\s_-]?(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z\d])\s+(?=[\dA-Za-z])/)`

Comment: @thetailor.de tried it. didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex to fix your problem:

```
/\s+|[-_]*(?=[A-Z])/
```

**Code:**

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
    let k = str.split(/\s+|[-_]*(?=[A-Z])/g).join('-').toLowerCase();
    console.log(k);
    return k;
}

spinalCase('This Is Spinal Tap'); //passed
spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap"); //passed
spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show"); //passed
spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh"); //passed
spinalCase("AllThe-small Things"); //passed
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `|`: OR
- `[-_]*(?=[A-Z])`: Match 0 or more of underscore or hyphen if that followed by an uppercase letter